# Is it possible to use a custom URN prefix in Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

Is it possible to use a custom URN prefix in Redis?  I'm trying to find a way to delineate the data in each of our frameworks within a single Redis instance.  For example, for our financial system I'd like to use "fin:Batch:1234".  Is there any harm in doing this?  If it helps, I'm planning on using Service Stack and Redis Desktop Manager during development.

Answer (score -1):

No harm at all. Keep in mind that Redis limits the size of key names to 512MB so try to stay below that for with your URNs :)

Seriously though, I don't know how many keys you are planning to have, but the shorter your key names are, the less memory your dataset will consume.

Comment: You'd want this if you would like to separate application parts so you can invalidate separate parts.